# Jinja convert chat.js charts to images when rendering template

Tags: javascript, python, html, chart.js, jinja2

I have a question about javascript within Jinja2 before I start on my project, so I can understand if jinja is the right solution to use

- I want to create an html email template that will fill in some values for each user, and then send them the rendered template via email. I already have the email functionality set up
- I want to include some charts from chart.js on the page, but because JS isn't allowed on emails I have to convert the charts to images before sending the email.

##### My question is, does jinja allow for this to happen when rendering the template? Can I make sure that the charts are converted to images when the template is rendered, and all JS is removed/inactive before sending the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Jinja (or any similar template system) cannot convert JavaScript charts to images on the backend, because JavaScript runs in a browser, so you need a headless browser engine (or similar JS runtime) on the backend for the conversion. It's doable, but it will make your environment more complicated since you'll need to maintain a JS runtime as well along with the Python environment. If you want to go in this direction, have a look at [chartjs-node-canvas](https://github.com/SeanSobey/ChartjsNodeCanvas) that uses NodeJS to export a chart, or any headless browser.

However I highly recommend a different way: use a Python plotting library like [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/). In an email you cannot even use any JS interactivity anyways, so a static plotting library is perfect for this task. Furthermore it's Python, so no need to add a different runtime to your environment.

Comment: For doing it in matplotlib, I imagine that I would convert the chart to a png, store it, and then pass the path to the chart to an img tag in the jinja template. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes. For emails you need to use the absolute URL, since the users will download the image as a remote content from the server when reading the email. Or you can embed the image directly in the email, but it can increase the size of the email significantly.

Comment: thank you again, as this was the perfect solution for my usecase!